# Display multiple images in a AS3 DataGrid

Tags: actionscript-3, datagrid

I need to display multiple images in a datagrid but can't figure out how. I'm able to display one image implementing ICellRenderer. 
I haven't been able to figure out how to display more than once since ICellRenderer looks for a data key in the DataProvider and displays that.

Is there a different type of DataProvider that can be used or a different interface which can be implemented?

This is the code I'm using for the image loading:

```
package {
// Import the required component classes.
import fl.containers.UILoader;
import fl.controls.listClasses.ICellRenderer;
import fl.controls.listClasses.ListData;
import fl.core.InvalidationType;
import fl.data.DataProvider;
import flash.events.Event;

/**
 * This class creates a custom cell renderer which displays an image in a cell.
 * Make sure the class is marked "public" and in the case of our custom cell renderer, 
 * extends the UILoader class and implements the ICellRenderer interface.
 */
public class LoaderCellRenderer extends UILoader implements ICellRenderer {
    protected var _data:Object;
    protected var _listData:ListData;
    protected var _selected:Boolean;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public function LoaderCellRenderer():void {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * Gets or sets the cell's internal _data property.
     */
    public function get data():Object {
        return _data;
    }
    /** 
     * @private (setter)
     */
    public function set data(value:Object):void {
        _data = value;
        source = value.data;
    }

    /**
     * Gets or sets the cell's internal _listData property.
     */
    public function get listData():ListData {
        return _listData;
    }
    /**
     * @private (setter)
     */
    public function set listData(value:ListData):void {
        _listData = value;
        invalidate(InvalidationType.DATA);
        invalidate(InvalidationType.STATE);
    }

    /**
     * Gets or sets the cell's internal _selected property.
     */
    public function get selected():Boolean {
        return _selected;
    }
    /**
     * @private (setter)
     */
    public function set selected(value:Boolean):void {
        _selected = value;
        invalidate(InvalidationType.STATE);
    }

    /**
     * Sets the internal mouse state.
     */
    public function setMouseState(state:String):void {
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Found the answer. In the setter, if I change value.data to value.myotherimagekeyname it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You want to show multiple images in a single cell?
You should use a custom GridItemRenderer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:GridItemRenderer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" clipAndEnableScrolling="true">

 <fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        override public function prepare(hasBeenRecycled:Boolean):void {
            img1.source = data.image1Source;
            img2.source = data.image2Source;
        }
    ]]>
 </fx:Script>

 <s:HGroup>
    <s:Image id="img1" />
    <s:Image id="img2" />
 </s:HGroup>    
</s:GridItemRenderer>
```